# How do I set the size of a Pie Chart?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet that I want to insert a pie chart into. The code works but the pie chart is much too large and I can't find any documentation showing how to make it smaller. The code is as follows:

```
var chart = sheet.newChart()
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.PIE)
  .addRange(sheet.getRange(37, 20, data.length, data[0].length))
  .setPosition(4, 15, 2, 2)
  .setOption('height', 200)
  .build();

sheet.insertChart(chart);
```

setting the height to 200 changes the chart's container but the chart itself does not change. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `setOption('theme', 'maximized')` to the chartbuilder. That seemed to make the chart larger for me.

I was able to piece that through by looking at the options for a Piechart in screenshot below and the documentation for "theme" in the [Google Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart)

[image]